# Why does 'in window' in for loop initialization cause syntax error?

Tags: javascript

This works.

```
var a = 'ontouchstart' in window;
for (;;) {
  console.log(a);
  break;
}
```

This causes syntax error. Why?

```
for (var a = 'ontouchstart' in window;;) {
  console.log(a);
  break;
}
```

This works.

```
for (var a = ('ontouchstart' in window);;) {
  console.log(a);
  break;
}
```

Comment: The problem is some interpreter confusion over `for..in` and `prop in obj`, but I don't know exactly what it is. I'll do a little ECMAScript [grammar spelunking]http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4) and see if I can find anything useful.

Comment: @apsillers: It seems curious to me that both `=` and `;;` don't make the intention clear to the interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This causes syntax error. Why?

To avoid confusion with for-in-loops. The [syntax specification for for-loops](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.3) is explicit:

> `IterationStatement : for ( ExpressionNoIn`<sub>`opt`</sub>`; Expression`<sub>`opt`</sub>`; Expression`<sub>`opt`</sub>`) Statement`
>
> `IterationStatement : for ( var VariableDeclarationListNoIn ; Expression`<sub>`opt`</sub>`; Expression`<sub>`opt`</sub>`) Statement`

This `NoIn` suffix spreads through the whole syntactic grammar, and ends in the [11.8 Relational Operators (Syntax) section](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8):

```
RelationalExpression :

ShiftExpression
RelationalExpression < ShiftExpression
RelationalExpression > ShiftExpression
RelationalExpression <= ShiftExpression
RelationalExpression >= ShiftExpression
RelationalExpression instanceof ShiftExpression
RelationalExpression in ShiftExpression

RelationalExpressionNoIn :

ShiftExpression
RelationalExpressionNoIn < ShiftExpression
RelationalExpressionNoIn > ShiftExpression
RelationalExpressionNoIn <= ShiftExpression
RelationalExpressionNoIn >= ShiftExpression
RelationalExpressionNoIn instanceof ShiftExpression
```

> **NOTE: The `NoIn` variants are needed to avoid confusing the in operator in a relational expression with the in operator in a for statement.**

However, I don't understand myself why the `NoIn` variants are used in the normal for-loop - they are reasonable in for-in-productions. I'd guess it's to avoid confusion of the programmer and to simplify parsers.

Comment: If I understand the note correctly, this is meant to avoid confusing the learning programmer, not the interpreter (which should be able to figure it out because of `;;`), right?

Comment: @pdknsk: Yes, I have spent some time figuring out whether the two semicolons were allowed in the `LeftHandSideExpression`/`VariableDeclarationNoIn` of for-in-loops (afaict no), and came to the same conclusion